# Write a CSV using PHP

Tags: php, csv, using

I have three questions in hand

1. i have no problem in export the data from php to csv. But i have struggled to put the 
    in of csv coloumn. Here the detail

   1. PostId    PostTitle   Reply                  Ip
   2. 1. 1         test        reply 1               127.0.0.1
   3. reply 2
   4. reply 3
   5. 1. 
   6. 2         test2       response 1            127.0.0.1
   7. response 2
   8. 

In the above example i have export the all the data's into csv. But in "Reply" column i can not give the 
 between the reply/response. How i can separate each reply's? if am using  $csv_output1 .= strip_tags("\"".$response."\""); i getting junk characters in csv

1. While i write a csv file, i need to wrap the top 3 columns to show the CSV title example "Ticketing Management system", after three rows only it show the data with column title
2. Is any body can help to use fputcsv()

Comment: "CSV" means "comma separated values". What character are you using to separate the columns? Also please show some code.

Comment: The manual on fputcsv() has an example: http://php.net/fputcsv

Answer (score 0):

Here my code

`$table = 'ost_ticket';
$file = 'TicketsOpen';

$csv_output = "SNO,Type,Date/Time Stamp,Subject,Response";//Header start here
$csv_output .= "\n";

$sql='SELECT dept_name,ost_ticket.created,subject,ticket_id FROM ost_ticket, ost_department
  WHERE ost_ticket.dept_id = ost_department.dept_id
  AND ost_ticket.created LIKE "'.$viewMonth.'-%" AND (';
  $f=$_REQUEST['f'];
  $k=0;
  while($k

while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {

$csv_output.=$sno++.",";
  for ($j=0;$j

// echo $rowr[3]."
";
  //echo "
".
   $sql1='SELECT response FROM  ost_ticket_response WHERE ticket_id ="'.$rowr[3].'"'; // Get Multiple response for a single ticket

$values1=mysql_query($sql1);

while (list($response) = mysql_fetch_row($values1)) {
    //$response=strip_tags($response,"
");
    //echo "
".addslashes($response);
    $csv_output1 .= strip_tags("\"".$response."\"");

  }
 $csv_output .= $csv_output1; //Get multiple response for a single column called //ticket response
  unset($csv_output1);
   $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>`

```
I want the csv output as like below

   c1    c2         c3                c4                c5

R1  
       -------------- Ticketing Management System -----------------

R2

R3  SNO    Type     Date/Time Stamp   Subject             Response


R4  1.    Server    Date comes        Title of ticket     Response 1

                                                          Response 2

R5  2     Tech      Date come         Title of ticket2    Response 1

                                                          Response 2

                                                          Response 3
```